# rstudio diagnostics synthax issue

Tags: rstudio

I've just noticed that my Rstudio isn't showing any of the usual synthax diagnostics. I'v checked thought the options menu and they are definitely on. I tried resetting Rstudio but didn't make any difference. Has anyone come across this and if so how do I fix it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know. It automatically started working again quite randomly. Must have been a small bug of some sort.

Cheers